# Refresh only datatable data Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im using Jquery datatable to draw a table from an API.And I want to reload the table without getting the re initializing error(only table data if possible) in every 5 seconds.Here is my Code.

```
var ajax_call$ = function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "rank" },
            { "data": "name" },
            {
                "data": "market_cap_usd", render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return '$' + data;
                }
            },
            {
                "data": "price_usd", render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return '$' + data;
                }
            },
            {
                "data": "24h_volume_usd", render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return '$' + data;
                }
            },
            { "data": "available_supply" },
            { "data": "percent_change_24h" }
        ]
    });

};

$(document).ready(function () {
    ajax_call$();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,
2 things,

One change

```
setInterval( function () {
        table.ajax.reload();
    }, 5000 );
```

to

```
setInterval( submitData , 5000 );
```

and

```
table=$('#table').dataTable({
        "pagingType" : 'full_numbers',
         destroy: true,    //ADD DESTROY TRUE
.
.
.
..
```

Comment: I want to call the api again and again in 5 second intervals to check for data changes and update the table.Can I accomplish that from this?

Comment: Yes I did as you stated here.but still the values arnt changing.

Comment: It seems the values are changing only once.

Comment: The values are changes.It works.my eyes couldnt keep up :)

Comment: Now a slight problem occured.When I reload the page in every 5 seconds,whenever I go to a different page(assume 2nd page) after the 5 second break,I get redirected to the 1st Page.(Page as in pagination buttons).What can I do here?

Comment: You can use like following:  table.ajax.reload(null,false);

Comment: table.ajax.reload( null, false ); // user paging is not reset on reload

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
setInterval( function () {
        $("#example").DataTable().ajax.reload();
    }, 5000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
window.setInterval(function(){
$("#TableID").DataTable().ajax.reload()
},5000);
```